# Does a String Replacing script affect shortcode output?

Tags: shortcode

I have some javascript in the header that finds and replaces any phone number string in the static html output of the page. It's working great on strings that are outputted by the_content, but for some reason it's not switching out the phone number that is output via a shortcode function.

Here's the line from the function that should be affected:

```
$cta .= '<span id="cta-phone"><a href="tel://303-232-6611"><i class="icon-phone"></i> 303-328-3091</a></span>';
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about a JS Script on the frontend (because you say header) or a PHP filter in the backend?

Comment: JS Script on the frontend

Comment: Then it shouldn't make any difference as shortcodes are parsed on the backend. Please add the code of the replacing script as the problem probably is there.